# Magento 2 get product details in product review list phtml?

Tags: magento2, product, customer, product-view, review

How can I get **product details** like product type and name in particular product reviews list page.

Actually I want to Display "**Product-Name reviews**" Instead of "**Customer Reviews**" in product detail page.

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Are you want to get product name in review tab in details page

Comment: yes, In place of ''customers review' I need '[product name] review'.

Comment: We can get product data directly on our template: `$block->getProduct()` in our template.

Comment: ok @KhoaTruongDinh, Will try this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy `product/view/list.phtml` to your custom theme. We get product data directly on our template: `$block->getProduct()`.

*app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Review/templates/product/view/list.phtml*

```
<?php $productName = $block->getProduct()->getName(); ?>

 <div class="block-title">
    <!--        <strong>--><?php ///* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Reviews') ?><!--</strong>-->
    <strong><?php  echo $productName; ?></strong>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can get product id from review block

**Magento\Review\Block\Product\View\ListView.php**

```
public function getProductId()
    {
        $product = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('product');
        return $product ? $product->getId() : null;
    }
```

in phtml get id of product

```
$block->getProductId();
```

Comment: ok, @Fme I wil try this.